# How to retrieve extended Facebook information from list members

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My first actual question for your perusal. I am attempting to modify a javascript code snippet. This code deals with returning members of the users friends lists. We are loading the fbjssdk and initializing everything correctly. The container referenced in the function is loading list members correctly.

```
var TargetFriendListed = function(id) {
var container = $('#targetFriends ul');
container.empty();

FB.api('/' + id + '/members', function(res) {
    $.each(res.data, function(i, val) {
        new Friend(val.id,val.name);
    });
    container.selectable();
    Progress.hide(Progress.TEXT_COMPLETE);
});
};

var Friend = function(id, name) {

var container = $('#targetFriends ul');
var elm = $('<li facebook_id="'+id+'"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '/picture" alt="" width="75px" height="75px"><span>'+name+'</span></li>');
container.append(elm);
};
```

What I would like to do is take the id that is returned from the friends list members call and run it against the API again to retrieve gender, location, and birth date if privacy settings allow this. I could then sort the results based on the extended information.

My question is specifically what is the best method, resource and time wise.